# ASP.NET MVC retain query parameter across all requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, httprequest, url-parameters

For development purposes, I want to always retain a certain query parameter on every single URL request if the hostname is localhost.

So for example if I have: `http://localhost:12345/Home?myParam=myVal`, then for every single request, I want to append the `myParam=myVal` onto the querystring if the `hostname == "localhost"`.

Is there a way in my `BaseController` class to preserve this parameter?  The reason I want to do this is so that after the developer rebuilds the project, since the `FormsAuthentication` is still active (which is a good thing), I want to also retain this parameter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Custom `Route` class

That's the answer. Inherit from existing `Route` class and change your `GetVirtualPath` according to your needs (append parameter).

IN case you don't want your users to see/change the query value you should rather change the `GetRouteData` method and append your custom value (as always the same) when request comes from localhost.